# Rxjava, repeat existing item when error occur

Tags: java, spring-boot, rx-java, reactive-programming

here's my operation, 
when error, i hope `retryWhen`  would repeat current item s, But it would repeat the whole process from beginning, i tried modified this but it will not repeat and throw exception.

```
return Observable.fromArray(getTodayShareHolding(dd,MM,yyyy,tmpTicker, item.getId())).retryWhen(errors -> errors.flatMap(error -> Observable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) ) );
```

then i tried modified the code like this

```
@GetMapping(path = "operaion")
    public @ResponseBody void operation(@RequestParam(value = "startDate", required = true) String startDate, @RequestParam(value = "endDate", required = true) String endDate ) throws IOException, ParseException {

        List <EntityList> plist = EntityListListRepository.findByPendingDayBetweenAndIsProcessedFalseAndIsUpdatedFalse(formatDate(startDate), formatDate(endDate) );                 
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Observable.fromIterable(plist).concatMap( item -> {             
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();                                  
                cal.setTime(item.getPendingDay());
                Integer yyyy = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                Integer MM = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
                Integer dd = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                String tmpId = item.getTmpId().toString();
                Integer delayCheck = item.getTmpId();
                Integer delayMiniSec = 0;

                if(delayCheck >= 70000) {
                        delayMiniSec = 0;

                }
                Date currentTime = new Date();      
                System.out.println("Step1 ::{ : "+dd+"/"+MM+"/"+yyyy+"@"+tmpId+" id = ["+item.getId()+"] } startInsert time = "+currentTime);
                return Observable.fromArray(fetchList(dd,MM,yyyy,tmpId, item.getId()))

            }).retryWhen(errors -> errors.flatMap(error -> Observable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) ) );
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

and it's going to repeat the whole process when expetion occur, 
any give me some suggestion?

Updated:
Or I try something like this below?
http://aspects.jcabi.com/annotation-retryonfailure.html

Comment: So what you want is `1->2->3->error->3->4->...` but not `1->2->3->error->1->2->3->...`, yes?

Comment: yes, please guide me

Comment: When error occur, the upstream was broken. `retry` resubscribe on upstream to recover the stream. So the difficulty is how to recover the upstream to the specify status. I think there is no common way. And in your case, it doesn't need rxjava.